# What cautions one should be aware of before handing out an .exe file

Tags: visual-studio-2005, x86, unmanaged, software-distribution

Does an .exe contain any personal computer information (what if any) that must be taken care of and what must be done before giving out a standalone .exe file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only personal information is path to `.pdb` file, like "c:\path\to\outdir\Release\program.pdb".
It may be useful for post-mortem debugging, so just change output directory if needed.

Comment: That is what I believed. I changed the output directory but now it generates the .pdb in that directory on release build.

Comment: @Dave18: You can just delete the .pdb file, or tell VS not to create it in the first place under Release mode by setting the Advanced Compile Options in your project's Properties.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your development system and your configuration. For example, if you use Visual Studio, new projects will include your name as VS is registered.

The first step is to right click the exe, go to properties and see what information is there.

The second thing would be to use a resource editor to see what resources are stored in your exe (however, if you wrote it, you may well know those resources already).

Answer (score 0):

If the EXE you have yourself coded, it might be disassembled to discover logic or even alter the logic of program using various disassembler , hex editors.

You might want to look into packing and obfuscation if you want to prevent this.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_engineering

Comment: If this is *really* a concern, good luck protecting it with any kind of obfuscation technology. You're only going to deter the most casual or inexperienced of hackers, and they probably weren't going to try in the first place.

Comment: If your not careful about your packing, it can lead to false positives, which may cause more problems than its worth